getx controllers are not called properly
I am making a news app in flutter using Getx as statemanagement.
Flow
if already have acount
LoginSreen-> MainScreen(FeedNewsScreen)
if new user
SingupScreen -> interestScreen -> LoginSreen-> MainScreen(FeedNewsScreen)
PROBLEMS

when ever i am starting app its creating and initializing  Authcontroller then creating feednewscontroller (which i didn't call) then exploreNewsController(again not called ) then BottomNavigationController

After New Account have been created and i am loging into my account then its showing me no interest found but interest list is populated but interests as fetchedIntersts methods is called from login method in authcontroller .


3 when using Get.put(feednewscontroller) in mainscreen after navigation from loging screen or opening the app if already loged in i think the init of feednewscontroller is not working as this is responsible for fetching the news
this is my main file


Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});
  final AuthController authController =
      Get.put(AuthController(), permanent: true);
  final BottomNavigationController navigationController =
      Get.put(BottomNavigationController(), permanent: true);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() {
      if (navigationController.themeMode.value == null ||
          authController.user == null) {
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      }

      return GetMaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
        darkTheme: AppTheme.darkTheme,
        themeMode: navigationController.themeMode.value,
        home: authController.isUserLoggedIn() ? MainPage() : WelcomePage(),
      );
    });
  }
}


this is AuthController


class AuthController extends GetxController {
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  UserPreference pref = UserPreference();
  UserModel user = UserModel();
  RxList<String> interests = <String>[].obs;
  RxInt maxInterest = 0.obs;
  RxBool isPressedSignin = false.obs;
  // FeedNewsController feedNewsController = Get.find();

  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    user = await pref.getUser();
    if (user.isLogin == true) {
      await fetchInterests();
    }
  }

  Future<bool> register(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      await _setUserToken(userCredential);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("Error", e.toString(), snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<bool> login(String email, String password) async {
    bool interestFetched = false;

    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      user = UserModel(
          isLogin: true,
          token: await userCredential.user!.getIdToken(),
          uid: userCredential.user!.uid);
      pref.saveUser(user);
      interestFetched = await fetchInterests();
      // pref.saveInterest(interests);
      // feedNewsController.fetchEveryThingNews();

      print("interest fetched $interestFetched");

      return interestFetched;
    } catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar("Error", e.toString(), snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
      return interestFetched;
    }
  }

  Future<void> logOut() async {
    await auth.signOut();
    pref.removeUser();
    interests.clear();
  }

  Future<void> _setUserToken(UserCredential userCredential) async {
    User? user = userCredential.user;
    if (user != null) {
      String? token = await user.getIdToken();
      await firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
        'token': token,
      }, SetOptions(merge: true));
    }
  }

  Future<bool> fetchInterests() async {
    User? currentUser = auth.currentUser;
    if (currentUser != null) {
      DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot =
          await firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).get();
      Map<String, dynamic>? userData = snapshot.data();
      if (userData != null && userData['interests'] != null) {
        interests.assignAll(List<String>.from(userData['interests']));
        print(interests);
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<void> updateInterests() async {
    User? currentUser = auth.currentUser;
    if (currentUser != null) {
      await firestore.collection('users').doc(currentUser.uid).set({
        'interests': interests.toList(),
      });
    }
    print('saved  $interests');
    interests.clear();
  }

  bool isUserLoggedIn() {
    return user.isLogin ?? false;
  }
}


this is FeedNewsController


class FeedNewsController extends GetxController {
  final NewsRepo _newsRepo = NewsRepo();
  UserPreference pref = UserPreference();
  AuthController authController = Get.find();
  RxInt page = 1.obs;
  RxInt pageSize = 10.obs;
  RxList<Articles> everyThingNews = <Articles>[].obs;
  RxBool isLoading = false.obs;
  RxBool isLoadingMore = false.obs;
  RxList<String> sortBy = ['relevancy', 'popularity', 'publishedAt'].obs;
  RxString currentSort = 'relevancy'.obs;
  RxString errorMessage = ''.obs;

  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    authController.fetchInterests;
    print('${authController.interests}');
    await fetchEveryThingNews();
  }

  Future<void> fetchEveryThingNews() async {
    print('everything news called');
    try {
      isLoading(true);
      List interests = authController.interests;
      print(interests);
      // List<String> interests = await pref.getInterest();
      if (interests.isEmpty) {
        print("$interests  no interst found");

        errorMessage('no interst found.');
        return;
      }
      String interestsQuery =
          interests.map((interest) => '"$interest"').join(' OR ');
      NewsModel newsModel = await _newsRepo.fetchEverythingNews(
        search: interestsQuery,
        page: page.value.toString(),
        pageSize: pageSize.value.toString(),
        sortBy: currentSort.value,
      );
      everyThingNews.value = _removeDuplicates(newsModel.articles ?? []);
    } catch (e) {
      errorMessage(e.toString());
    } finally {
      isLoading(false);
    }
  }

  Future<void> fetchMoreNews() async {
    try {
      isLoadingMore(true);
      page.value++;
      List<String> interests = authController.interests;
      String interestsQuery =
          interests.map((interest) => '"$interest"').join(' OR ');
      NewsModel newsModel = await _newsRepo.fetchEverythingNews(
        search: interestsQuery,
        page: page.value.toString(),
        pageSize: pageSize.value.toString(),
        sortBy: currentSort.value,
      );
      everyThingNews.addAll(_removeDuplicates(newsModel.articles ?? []));
    } catch (e) {
      errorMessage(e.toString());
    } finally {
      isLoadingMore(false);
    }
  }

  List<Articles> _removeDuplicates(List<Articles> articles) {
    final uniqueArticles = <String>{};
    final filteredArticles = <Articles>[];

    for (var article in articles) {
      if (uniqueArticles.add(article.title!)) {
        filteredArticles.add(article);
      }
    }

    return filteredArticles;
  }
}


this is singup Screen


class SignUpScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  SignUpScreen({super.key});

  final TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  final AuthController authController = Get.find();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(AppDimension().defaultMargin),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 100,
              ),
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Text(
                    ' Get the latest news right away',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                  )),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Email',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: email,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "email",
                  prefixIcon: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Icon(Icons.person),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 24,
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Password',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: password,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "password",
                  prefixIcon: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Icon(Icons.lock),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 16),
              Obx(
                () => ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    String xemail = email.text.trim();
                    String xpassword = password.text.trim();
                    if (xemail.isEmpty || xpassword.isEmpty) {
                      print('empty fields;');
                    } else {
                      authController.isPressedSignin.value = true;
                      print(authController.isPressedSignin.value);
                      bool isSigned =
                          await authController.register(xemail, xpassword);
                      if (isSigned) {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => InterestsScreen(),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor:
                          const WidgetStatePropertyAll(AppColor.primary),
                      shape: WidgetStatePropertyAll(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)))),
                  child: authController.isPressedSignin.value
                      ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                      : Text(
                          "sign up".toUpperCase(),
                        ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 8),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


this is Interest screen (where users will pick interests )



class InterestsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  InterestsScreen({super.key});
  AuthController authController = Get.find();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(
      () => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: AppDimension().defaultMargin),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 24,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Wrap(
                    alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                    children: AppString.newsTopics
                        .map(
                          (e) => Padding(
                            padding:
                                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0),
                            child: FilledButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (authController.interests.contains(e)) {
                                  authController.interests.remove(e);

                                  authController.maxInterest--;
                                  print(
                                      "removed   $authController.maxInterest");
                                } else {
                                  if (authController.maxInterest.value >= 5) {
                                    Get.snackbar("Limit reached",
                                        "You can choose only 5 interests",
                                        snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
                                  } else {
                                    authController.interests.add(e);
                                    authController.maxInterest++;
                                    print(
                                        "added   $authController.maxInterest");
                                  }
                                }
                              },
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                  shape: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
                                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                          side: const BorderSide(
                                              color: AppColor.light))),
                                  backgroundColor: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
                                      authController.interests.contains(e)
                                          ? AppColor.primary
                                          : Colors.transparent)),
                              child: Text(
                                e,
                                style: const TextStyle(color: AppColor.light),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 16,
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                  horizontal: AppDimension().defaultMargin),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor:
                          const WidgetStatePropertyAll(AppColor.primary),
                      shape: WidgetStatePropertyAll(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4)))),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (authController.interests.isEmpty) {
                      Get.snackbar("No Interests Selected",
                          "Please select at least one interest.",
                          snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
                    } else {
                      authController.updateInterests();
                      Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => LoginScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Done')),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

this is Login Screen


class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  LoginScreen({super.key});

  TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password = TextEditingController();
  AuthController authController = Get.find();
  BottomNavigationController navigationController = Get.find();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(AppDimension().defaultMargin),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 100,
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Lets LogIn',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 40,
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Email',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: email,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onSaved: (email) {},
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "email",
                  prefixIcon: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Icon(Icons.person),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 24,
              ),
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Password',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: password,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "password",
                  prefixIcon: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Icon(Icons.lock),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 24,
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  String xemail = email.text.trim();
                  String xpassword = password.text.trim();
                  bool isLoggedIn =
                      await authController.login(xemail, xpassword);
                  if (isLoggedIn) {
                    navigationController.currentIndex.value = 0;

                    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage()),
                      (Route<dynamic> route) => false,
                    );
                  }
                },
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor:
                      const WidgetStatePropertyAll(AppColor.primary),
                  shape: WidgetStatePropertyAll(RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4))),
                ),
                child: Text(
                  "Login".toUpperCase(),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 8,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

this is Main Screen(contains feed Screen)


class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  MainPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('main screen called');
    final BottomNavigationController navigationController =
        Get.find<BottomNavigationController>();
    // Get.lazyPut(() => FeedNewsController(), fenix: true);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Obx(() =>
          navigationController.pages[navigationController.currentIndex.value]),
      bottomNavigationBar: Obx(
        () => BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: (value) => navigationController.onTabTapped(value),
          currentIndex: navigationController.currentIndex.value,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.grid_view_outlined),
              label: 'Feed',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.explore_outlined),
              label: 'Explore',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person_4_outlined),
              label: 'Profile',
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


this is feed Screen

class FeedScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final FeedNewsController newsController = Get.find();
  final AppDimension dimension = AppDimension();
  final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController();

  FeedScreen({super.key}) {
    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
  }

  void _onScroll() {
    if (_scrollController.position.atEdge) {
      bool isBottom = _scrollController.position.pixels != 0;
      if (isBottom) {
        newsController.fetchMoreNews();
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 5,
          title: SizedBox(height: 20, child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png')),
        ),
        body: Obx(() {
          if (newsController.isLoading.value) {
            return const Center(child: AppWidgets.loadingIndicator);
          } else if (newsController.errorMessage.isNotEmpty) {
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${newsController.errorMessage}'));
          } else if (newsController.everyThingNews.isEmpty) {
            return const Center(child: Text('No news articles available.'));
          } else {
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: _scrollController,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 21),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(dimension.defaultMargin)
                        .copyWith(bottom: 0, top: 0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        Text('My Feed',
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge),
                        const Spacer(),
                        const Icon(Icons.search),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  CarouselSlider.builder(
                    itemCount: 5,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                      return NewsCard(
                          news: newsController.everyThingNews[index]);
                    },
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                      height: 235,
                      viewportFraction: .8,
                      enlargeStrategy: CenterPageEnlargeStrategy.scale,
                      enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                      initialPage: 2,
                      autoPlay: true,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 12),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(dimension.defaultMargin)
                        .copyWith(bottom: 0, top: 0),
                    child: Row(
                      children: [
                        DropdownButton<String>(
                          value: newsController.currentSort.value,
                          items: newsController.sortBy.map((String value) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                              value: value,
                              child: Text(value,
                                  style: Theme.of(context)
                                      .textTheme
                                      .headlineMedium),
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (newValue) {
                            newsController.currentSort.value = newValue!;
                            newsController.page.value = 1;
                            newsController.fetchEveryThingNews();
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 16),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(dimension.defaultMargin)
                        .copyWith(bottom: 0, top: 0),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: newsController.everyThingNews.length +
                          (newsController.isLoadingMore.value ? 1 : 0),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        if (index < newsController.everyThingNews.length) {
                          final newsArticle =
                              newsController.everyThingNews[index + 5];
                          return Column(
                            children: [
                              NewsTile(news: newsArticle),
                              const Divider(height: 32),
                            ],
                          );
                        } else {
                          return const Center(
                              child: AppWidgets.loadingIndicator);
                        }
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}


this is BottomNavigationController


class BottomNavigationController extends GetxController{
  RxInt currentIndex =0.obs;
   Rx<ThemeMode> themeMode  = ThemeMode.dark.obs;



  RxList pages=[
    FeedScreen(),
    ExploreScreen(),
    ProfileScreen()

  ].obs;
  
  void onTabTapped(int index) {
      currentIndex.value = index;
  
  }
   void toggleThemeMode() {
      themeMode.value =
          themeMode.value == ThemeMode.light ? ThemeMode.dark : ThemeMode.light;
  }
}

I want

when i login or open app , then feed news should get fetched and show on screen or intersts list gets populate if its causig the problem
Controllers should not  get initialize unnecesserly .


Welcome to SO. That is a LOT of code for us to parse through. Also, the exact issue is not clear. Please take a moment and review How to ask a question and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Reduce the code and clarify the question and we'll take a look!

I think the problem in BottomNavigationController you need to provide to post the code of BottomNavigationController

i  just added  it  at last  of question

this is your problem in this section
RxList pages=[
FeedScreen(),
ExploreScreen(),
ProfileScreen()
].obs;
you need to create paging navigation and moving from page to another using the getx navigation system , because now using this code the object from these classes was created so using this approach an object from  FeedScreen was created in the same moment that the BottomNavigationController was created in.
see this article to learn more about navigation using getx
https://medium.com/@pietechnolabs/mastering-navigation-in-flutter-with-getx-a-deep-dive-a738195c8ee6

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
